# How to use bob.measure.load.split()

Tags: python-bob

I'm a student studying with a focus on machine learning, and I'm interested in authentication.
I am interested in your library because I want to calculate the EER.

Sorry for the basic question, but please tell me about `bob.measure.load.split()`.

Is the file format required by this correct in the perception that the first column is the correct label and the second column is the predicted score of the model?

like

```
# file.txt    
|label|prob |
| -1  | 0.3 |
| 1   | 0.5 |
| -1  | 0.8 |
```

...

In addition, to actually calculate the EER, should I follow the following procedure?

```
neg, pos = bob.measure.load.split('file.txt')
eer = bob.measure.eer(neg, pos)
```

Sincerely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options of calculating EER with bob.measure:

1. Use the Python API to calculate EER using numpy arrays.
2. Use the command line application to generate error rates (including EER) and plots

## Using Python API

First, you need to load the scores into memory and split them into *positive* and *negative* scores.
For examples:

```py
import numpy as np
import bob.measure
positives = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.2])
negatives = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2])
eer = bob.measure.eer(negatives, positives)
print(eer)
```

This will print `0.2`. All you need to take care is that your positive comparison scores are higher than negative comparisons. That is your model should score higher for positive samples.

## Using command line

bob.measure also comes with a suite of command line commands that can help you get the error rates. To use the command line, you need to save the scores in a text file. This file is made of two columns *where columns are separated by **space***. For example the score file for the same example would be:

```sh
$ cat scores.txt
1 0.5
1 0.5
1 0.6
1 0.7
1 0.2
-1 0.0
-1 0.0
-1 0.6
-1 0.2
-1 0.2
```

and then you would call

```sh
$ bob measure metrics scores.txt
[Min. criterion: EER ] Threshold on Development set `scores.txt`: 3.500000e-01
================================  =============
..                                Development
================================  =============
False Positive Rate               20.0% (1/5)
False Negative Rate               20.0% (1/5)
Precision                         0.8
Recall                            0.8
F1-score                          0.8
Area Under ROC Curve              0.8
Area Under ROC Curve (log scale)  0.7
================================  =============
```

Ok it didn't print EER exactly but `EER = (FPR+FNR)/2`.

## Using bob.bio.base command line

If your scores are the results of a biometrics experiment,
then you want to save your scores in the 4 or 5 column formats of bob.bio.base.
See an example in https://gitlab.idiap.ch/bob/bob.bio.base/-/blob/3efccd3b637ee73ec68ed0ac5fde2667a943bd6e/bob/bio/base/test/data/dev-4col.txt and documentation in https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/docs/bob/bob.bio.base/stable/experiments.html#evaluating-experiments
Then, you would call `bob bio metrics scores-4-col.txt` to get biometrics related metrics.